# If i am not using ag-Grid's built-in filtering and instead implementing my own filtering logic, then can i get directly getFilterModel() object?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using Ag-Grid-React, I have applied my own filter in ag-grid-react.
So can i get Filter object using getFilterModal() ?

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const selectedValue = event?.target?.value || event; 
    setSelectedOption(selectedValue);
   
    const savedFilterModel = gridRef.current.api.getFilterModel();
    console.log(savedFilterModel);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedOption) {
      const filteredRows = rowData.filter((row) => row.country === selectedOption);
      setFilteredData(filteredRows);
    } else {
      setFilteredData(rowData);
    }
  }, [selectedOption, rowData]);

<div style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
            <label >Choose a country:</label>

            <select style={{ marginLeft: "15px" }} value={selectedOption} onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
            </select>

        </div>

        <div style={containerStyle}>
            <div style={gridStyle} className='ag-theme-alpine'>
                <AgGridReact
                    ref={gridRef}
                    rowData={filteredData}
                    columnDefs={columnDefs}
                    onFilterChanged={() => handleChange(selectedOption)}></AgGridReact>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So can i get directly access the getFilterModel() function provided by ag-Grid.